# SpringBoot - @RequestMapping(name = "/home") - @RequestMapping(value = "/home")

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

I have some issues with Spring Boot.

When im using `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")`, everything works fine for me. But when im using `@RequestMapping(name = "/home")`, my site won't show up.

So my question is: What is the difference between `@RequestMapping(name = "/home")` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")`?

Comment: it is explained in the Javadoc of that annotation

Comment: I know.. But i cant see wheres the difference. Btw.. if i use path instead of value it works as well. So just tell me why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per I know name in @RequestMapping is used for assigning name to the mapping.

```
What is Name? 
As In servlet mapping we assign name to the servlet class and url pattern
in spring we can also assign name to the mapping.
```

But values is different, it is used for defining URL Pattern by which we can invoke the method of the Controller class.